# Inserting String in a file using java

Tags: java, xml, file-io

I am trying to insert string value in an xml file , but I am not getting exactly how to insert using java.

```
textFieldChoose.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());

                    String str="";

                  final JFrame msgframe= new JFrame();
                  msgframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                  str= textFieldChoose.getText();
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textFieldChoose, str);
                  ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
                  str= textFieldChoose.getText();
```

I can store the value in a string. I need to replace that value every time when whenever my application will pick another value in the string.

**xml:-**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="org.world.rg" default="rg.init" basedir=".">

  <property name="dita.dir" location="${basedir}/../../.."/>

  <target name="rg.init" description="build PDF" depends="pdf"/>


  <target name="pdf" description="build PDF">
    <ant antfile="${dita.dir}/build.xml">
      <property name="args.input" location=""/>
```

*I need to insert that string value in `location =""/>` . what are the possible ways?*

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XPATH expression to update this element:

```
//project/target/ant/property ...
```

[How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Comment: I am  using this `XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/project/target[1]/ant/property/@location";
 Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);           
  node.setTextContent(str);` but facing exceptions . Can you instruct correct way to follow tags according to my xml.

Comment: The location attribute must be in brackets: //Parent[@id='1']/Children/child[@location]

Comment: Throwing lots of exceptions

Answer (score 0):

A simple way with java 8 API Files, but I do not think it's the best, it would be:

1) Read file
2) replace value
3) write file

```
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("example.xml"));
String content = new String(fileContent)
                    .replace("location =\"\"", "location =\"" + str + "\"");
Files.write(Paths.get("example.xml"), xmlString.getBytes());
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this parameter ? `location =\"\"", "location =\"" + str + "\"")`

Comment: I was trying to be simple, this is just the use of the replace method that the object String in java has.

Comment: Yes, I got you , but I need t understand this way of passing location. `(location =\?"\" ?? " , "location =\" ? " + str + "\"?")`

Comment: Are you in doubt why I'm escape the double quotes?

Comment: No , I know to pass char in that , I am in confusion with the <tags> to pass in the parameter. ("old char", "char") . But how exactly I am not getting that.

Comment: Can you mention this `location =\"\"", "location =\"" + str + "\"")` according to my xml file , because i am having lots of error in passing between the tags

Comment: You need insert string value in <property name="args.input" location=""/>, right?

Comment: Yes , I just need to insert String value only in '"<property name="args.input" location=" ? "/>' (@location)

Comment: What are the mistakes? If location = "" is occurring more times, you can try to use a larger reference.

Comment: Not any mistake , I am unable to understand the node parsing. And input.arg location is not occurring more times , it is just updating/replacing the string (str) value. Just help me through the solution you had provided  `location =\"\"", "location =\"" + str + "\"")` explain this through my xml file.